# Error run node module in windows

Tags: json, reactjs, npm, webpack

I've a problem when running `npm run start-dev`. I didn't find how to fix it.
I need your help.

Here the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to install dependencies. Execute these 2 commands:

```
npm i -g webpack
npm i -g nodemon
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you max! but now another error appears:

$ npm run start-dev

> Transpeed@0.1.0 start-dev D:\Job\Tsuki Studio\project\transport
>   NODE_ENV=development webpack -w & NODE_ENV=development nodemon server.js

Webpack is watching the files…

(node:5256) DeprecationWarning: Chunk.modules is deprecated. Use Chunk.getNumberOfModules/mapModules/forEachModule/containsModule instead.
Hash: 78554cdef93f0cd841ef7c3729b001ec9190d7db
Version: webpack 3.1.0
Child
    Hash: 78554cdef93f0cd841ef
    Time: 22097ms
                     Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
        ./public/bundle.js  2.21 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
    ./public/bundle.js.map  2.61 MB       0  [emitted]         main
      [41] ./src/shared/helper/index.js 112 bytes {0} [built]
     [224] ./src/shared/reducers/index.js 245 bytes {0} [built]
     [225] ./src/shared/routes.js 307 bytes {0} [built]
     [298] ./src/browser/index.js 868 bytes {0} [built]
     [447] ./src/shared/configureStore.js 515 bytes {0} [built]
     [449] ./src/shared/reducers/Authentication.js 638 bytes {0} [built]
     [453] ./src/shared/reducers/User.js 319 bytes {0} [built]
     [455] ./src/shared/App.js 2.85 kB {0} [built]
     [456] ./src/shared/scenes/Dashboard/index.js 3.17 kB {0} [built]
     [461] ./src/shared/helper/Cookie.js 600 bytes {0} [built]
     [463] ./src/shared/helper/PrivateRoute.js 1.37 kB {0} [built]
     [464] ./src/shared/helper/authHeader.js 216 bytes {0} [built]
     [465] ./src/shared/helper/store.js 326 bytes {0} [built]
     [696] ./src/shared/scenes/Sign/scenes/Login/index.js 6.57 kB {0} [built]
     [697] ./src/shared/scenes/Users/index.js 12 kB {0} [built]
        + 725 hidden modules
Child
    Hash: 7c3729b001ec9190d7db
    Time: 31234ms
            Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
        server.js  3.07 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
    server.js.map  3.85 MB       0  [emitted]         main
      [43] ./src/shared/helper/index.js 112 bytes {0} [built]
     [161] ./src/shared/routes.js 307 bytes {0} [built]
     [162] ./src/shared/actions/index.js 47 bytes {0} [built]
     [280] ./src/shared/reducers/index.js 245 bytes {0} [built]
     [281] ./src/shared/HOC/index.js 51 bytes {0} [built]
     [357] ./src/server/index.js 3.02 kB {0} [built]
     [547] ./src/shared/scenes/Dashboard/index.js 3.17 kB {0} [built]
     [585] ./src/shared/helper/authHeader.js 216 bytes {0} [built]
     [586] ./src/shared/helper/store.js 326 bytes {0} [built]
     [587] ./src/shared/reducers/Authentication.js 638 bytes {0} [built]
     [588] ./src/shared/reducers/User.js 319 bytes {0} [built]
     [826] ./src/shared/scenes/Sign/scenes/Login/index.js 6.57 kB {0} [built]
     [827] ./src/shared/scenes/Users/index.js 12 kB {0} [built]
     [870] ./src/shared/configureStore.js 515 bytes {0} [built]
     [873] ./src/shared/App.js 2.85 kB {0} [built]
        + 870 hidden modules

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/express/lib/view.js
80:29-41 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./node_modules/encoding/lib/iconv-loader.js
9:12-34 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
```